# Identify the following table

Tags: latin-square

What is the name of the following table<sup>1,2</sup> of two digit numbers?

[image: Fibonacci-related table]

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub><sup>Can be found on pg. 10 of this [link](https://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf).</sup></sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub><sup>I've left some of the surrounding text for context.</sup></sub>

Comment: The table itself is, I suspect, wholly unrelated to the Fibonacci numbers (it appears in an inset and the Fibonaccis are written 'around' it).  To me it looks like a 10x10 [Orthogonal Latin Square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square) - possibly the original counterexample found via UNIVAC (see the 'Euler's conjecture disproved' section of the above link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called parker's eulerian 10X10 square., looks like it involves more combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a magic square with the rows and columns adding up to 495.

Edit: technically it's not a magic square since the diagonals don't sum to 495.

Comment: Does it relate to the Fibonacci sequence in any way?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it doesn't.  But I might be wrong.  It's very mysterious.

Comment: @daOnlyBG Why do you think this is not an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I thought WHY's second question was part of the original one, to which you responded with "...But I might be wrong." I'm deleting the comment now.